# Задержка ШИМ AVR Atmega16

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, avr

Использую аппаратный ШИМ на выводах PD4(oc1b) и PD5(oc1a) поочередно.
Нужно чтоб при шимировании одного из портов (PD4 или PD5) на любом другом порте выход шим выводить но с небольшой задержкой (200-400нСек).
Понятно наверно станет если посмотреть на рисунок.
Использую язык Си.
Возможно ли вообще подобное реализовать на данном микроконтроллере?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чёрный - захват, красный - генерация? Или оба на генерацию? Во втором случае проще.

Comment: @maestro Оба сигнала на генерацию.

Comment: Вообще с генерацией двух ШИМ-сигналов на каналах одного таймера проблем не возникает? Если вы просто их включите, то у вас получится подобный сигнал, только первые фронты у них будут совпадающие. Я глянул [даташит](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc2466.pdf), и у этих контроллеров есть функция Phase and Frequency Correct PWM mode. И похоже, это то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @maestro запустил ШИМ в режиме Phase Correct, в принципе получилось что хотел. Просимулировал в Протеусе и в железе (картинки прикрепил в вопросе). Задержка получается 500нСек при частоте контроллера 16МГц и 20кГц ШИМ. ICR1 = 400 с шагом в 1 (например: OCR1A = 40 и OCR1B = 41) как раз получается 500нСек - пойдет (может можно как то уменьшить, поменять делитель?). Но я немного затупил) и надо чтоб нижний ШИМ был инвертирован(первую картинку исправил)?

Comment: С инверсией разобрался, настраивается регистрами OCRnA. Собственно вопрос можно считать закрытым. @maestro Спасибо за помощь.